Salesforce Connect Custom Adapter with Microsoft Graph API - Pagination Issues and Excessive DataSource.Connection Initialization
I've implemented a custom adapter in Salesforce using Apex to connect to the Microsoft Graph API (specifically the messages endpoint). I'm running into performance and pagination issues that I'm unable to resolve.
Issue Summary:

Connection Initialization: My connection class, OutlookConnection, is initialized far more times than expected during query operations. For example, with a batch size of 200, it's initialized 24 times. Reducing the batch size to 10 increases this to 74. This behavior seems excessive and likely impacts performance.

Full Data Retrieval on List View: When querying data for a list view, I would expect only the initial batch of records to be retrieved. Instead, my code retrieves the entire dataset until the queryMore tokens are exhausted. This occurs even if only the first page (e.g., the first 50 records) is displayed, causing a significant delay. When scrolling down past the initial batch, I would expect the code to fetch only the next batch, but it re-fetches the same records instead.

Pagination: I’ve implemented pagination by setting the queryMoreToken in the DataSource.TableResult object returned by the query method. Despite this, the adapter is fetching all records in one go. Disabling the QUERY_PAGINATION_SERVER_DRIVEN functionality naturally doesn’t resolve the issue, and I’m unsure if a client-side approach to pagination is required here.


Code Excerpt:
Here's the relevant part of my OutlookConnection class where the issues seem to occur:
global class OutlookConnection extends DataSource.Connection {
    private DataSource.ConnectionParams connectionParams;
    private MappedColumnFactory mappedColumnFactory;
    private static final Integer BATCH_SIZE = 200;
    private static final String ENDPOINT = 'me/mailFolders(...)/messages';

    global OutlookConnection(DataSource.ConnectionParams connectionParams) {
        System.debug('Initializing connection... ' + System.now());
        this.connectionParams = connectionParams;
        this.mappedColumnFactory = new MappedColumnFactory();
    }

    override global DataSource.TableResult query(DataSource.QueryContext queryContext) {
        DataSource.TableResult queryResult;
        System.debug('Received query request... ' + System.now());

        QueryResultWrapper result = getInboxMessages(queryContext);

        if (result.ErrorCode != null) {
            queryResult = DataSource.TableResult.error(result.errorMessage);
        } else {
            queryResult = DataSource.TableResult.get(queryContext, result.Rows);
            queryResult.totalSize = result.Count;
            queryResult.queryMoreToken = result.NextLink;
        }

        return queryResult;
    }

    private QueryResultWrapper getInboxMessages(DataSource.QueryContext queryContext) {
        String url = queryContext.queryMoreToken;
        if (String.isBlank(url)) {
            url = generateUrl(queryContext);
            System.debug('Generated URL... ' + System.now() + ' ' + url);
        } else {
            System.debug('Using next link... ' + System.now() + ' ' + url);
        }

        return getData(queryContext, url);
    }
    // Additional helper methods are here...
}

What I’ve Tried:

Logging and debugging indicate that the connection class initializes multiple times based on batch size, which doesn’t seem right.
Removing the server-driven pagination capabilities didn't fix the full data retrieval issue.
Setting queryMoreToken appropriately but still seeing all records fetched on the first query, even when the UI should only require the initial batch.

Questions:

Is there a way to control or reduce the excessive initialization of the connection class?
Am I misconfiguring the queryMoreToken handling or DataSource.TableResult in a way that forces the full dataset to be retrieved upfront?
Do I need to implement client-side pagination, or is there a configuration I'm overlooking for server-driven pagination with Salesforce Connect?

Any guidance on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Question regarding (only) those instantiations of OutlookConnection that appear unnessary, because no implemented method is called by Salesforce: Did you see significant delays between "Initializing connection..." for these?

Server-Driven Paging
As long as Salesforce receives a queryMoreToken on the TableResult from the query method, it calls the method again. There is no other stoppage. "Server Driven" means for Salesforce (the number of callouts is) "not my responsibility".
So if a Salesforce List View is meant to render 50 lines initially and queryMoreToken is returned from the method call, things are unlikely to go well. When the list view is accessed first, everything is retrieved, although the UI only displays the first 50 lines. When the user scrolls beyond these 50, everything is retrieved again.
If you want to use Server-Driven Paging, you need a way to tell Microsoft not to return (what Microsoft calls) a @odata.nextLink after the required number of records are retrieved - or to stop passing it on to Salesforce's queryMoreToken.
Client-Driven Paging
For the given situation, this is an easier choice. queryMoreToken becomes unnecessary.
Instead offset and maxResults of the QueryContext are used, and queryMoreToken of TableResult is not populated.
From what I can tell, Microsoft supports this strategy by its $skip and $top parameters. In my tests,
.../v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$orderby=createdDateTime&$skip=18&$top=1

returned the 18th out of a batch of 19 messages. Salesforce's queryContext.offset maps to Microsoft's skip, Salesforce's queryContext.maxResult maps to Microsoft's top.
I assume the totalSize would at least require one extra Microsoft call of a specific type. But setting this variable is unnecessary.

If the configered BATCH_SIZE is larger than the number of records returned, nothing else is needed. (This is likely when rendering Salesforce List Views.)

If the configured BATCH_SIZE is smaller, Salesforce will stop calling query when the number of returned records is smaller than maxResults. (This is likely when doing SOQL on the External Object without a WHERE, setting out to retrieve 50000 records.) Here's one way one could implement something like this:


Integer top = BATCH_SIZE > queryContext.maxResults 
    ? queryContext.maxResults : BATCH_SIZE;
Integer skip = queryContext.offset;
List<OutlookData> rawRecords = new List<OutlookData>();
result.Rows = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
do {
    rawRecords = callMicrosoftGraphApi(top, skip);
    result.Rows.addAll(mapData(rawRecords));
    skip += top;
} while(rawRecords.size() == top);

Note that this still necessitates filtering data, if required.
Unnecessary instantiations of DataSource.Connection
Regarding how many times DataSource.Connection is instantiated (before and without query is being called): Indeed the constructor is called many more times than any method is called on the class - at least I observed this when rendering List Views. I don't see how we possibly could avoid this. In my test I didn't see a significant delay due to this.
In any case, the above strategy will significantly reduce the number of instantiations, because only the required number of records is retrieved and the paging is done inside the query method.
